# How to get the javascript to the clients, and how to implement caching when building a TMS?

Tags: javascript, tms

I am looking at making my own Tag Management System, or TMS: A system that manages javascript snippets over many sites, like analytics and ad-snippets, in such a way that you can, for example, change from google analytics to piwik analytics with just changing one tag. It would then automatically propagate to alle other connected sites. I've looked at the available options, and they either are too expensive, or far more feature rich than I need.

In this case, google is not your friend, as there are numerous marketing type articles about TMS'es and they entirely eclipse any articles about the technical challenges and how to's (if there are any).

The main problems I see now are how to get the javascript code to the sites that are connected to the TMS, and doing that without having to call the TMS every time.

Does anyone have an idea about this?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to propagate to multiple sites?

Comment: The javascript snippets...

Answer (score 0):

Their are two parts to your app. The first is the management console, That is where the user defines their tags: as you say ga, piwik etc.

The second is the client, where the user installs your small javascript snippet, like that of ga, which then installs the script tags based on the settings in the console.

The client is how you get java-script code to the sites, as it would need to contact your server with some form of api key, which would then return the script tags, and or java-script code required for that website, your client then inserts the scripts, tags into the page using dynamic injection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was looking for the term "dynamic injection". Now you told me, I can do some specific googlin' :-)

Comment: How would you cache things? Generate a per site cached file and serve that statically so it can be cached client side, or do something more advanced?

As an added bonus, the system should comply with the european cookie law, which means that some people get analytics, some ads, some both and some none at all... That would complicate things, as there are 6 categories, which means 2^6 permutations, although some are more likely than others...